# ssh2_connect not working with php

Tags: php

SSH2 connect isn't working with php although i am sure i install it on the server that i want to use to connect to the remote server

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
if (!($con = ssh2_connect("ip_goes here", 22))) {
  die('<div style="color:#333;font-size:18px">Server not reachable.Error 1002 </div>');
  }
echo "ssh2_connect finally works"; 
    ?>
```

I am getting `Server not reachable.Error 1002` and `Warning: ssh2_connect(): Unable to connect to ip_goes_here on port 22`

Btw i tried to connect to the ip via port 22 using putty and it works just fine.If  `ssh2_connect` didn't exist i would get `Undefined function error`

**EDIT**
I was able to connect to the ip via ssh fine

```
ssh root@xxx.xx.xxx.xxx
The authenticity of host 'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx (xxx.xx.xxx.xxx)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 3a:8b:14:a8:10:09:0a:2f:1a:c4:3b:c7:97:56:42:6e.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
```

Comment: Maybe the web server's IP blocked from connecting to the SSH server. It's kind of hard to debug a question like this without any more information. Are you able to ssh into the web server and try to ssh into the other server indirectly?

Comment: When sitting at the web server that's giving you the trouble, does `ssh user@<ip_goes here>` work for you?

Comment: @jww i tried ssh user@<ip_goes_here> on both sides and it worked perfect.See my edit

Comment: @user2650277 - your PHP code is probably not running as root. Please check with the user that the web server is running under.

Comment: @jww what you mean...the remote server that i am connecting to don't have php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with selinux and i had to disable it for ssh2 to connect